# NetDom at Startup

Tags: active-directory

We have a Bat file running on a pc login to migrate a pc from Domain A to Domain B  this works brill but.

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /c netdom move /domain:B %computername% /OU:"OU=Computers" /ud:B Admin /pd:***** /uo:%computername%\administrator /po:***** /uf:A admin /pf:******
```

We need this to be able to run at PC startup rather than user login. It looks like it runs but doesnt actually do anything. Any help would be brilliant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the "cmd /c" in there-- you can just run NETDOM by itself. (Assuming you're doing this from an AD startup script, you could even specify NETDOM as the executable for the startup script w/ the parameters you need, but it's probably better to use a script so that you can have more debugging ability).

It probably goes w/o saying, but be sure that NETDOM is in the path since you're not referencing it by an absolute path.

I'd modify the script to do something like:

```
netdom move /domain:B %computername% /OU:"OU=Computers" /ud:B Admin /pd:***** /uo:%computername%\administrator /po:***** /uf:A admin /pf:******
pause
```

Then, I'd add the "Run startup scripts visible / Enabled" setting to the GPO. On Windows XP, at least, you can see the output of the script in a window before logon. Then you can get some idea of what NETDOM is doing, since you'll see the output. (I believe Windows Vista / 7 "hide" the startup script output behind their idiotic full-screen display. For those OS's, you might be better off redirecting the output of NETDOM to something like %TEMP%\NETDOM.txt and looking at it there.)

I'd want the PC to reboot after NETDOM runs. Forcing a reboot in a startup script is needlessly difficult since SHUTDOWN doesn't work. I'd love somebody to tell me a good way to restart the PC in a startup script-- I've struggled with it for years and settled on killing LSASS.EXE as an imperfect but workable solution.

Comment: Did this but all it does is flash up like it runs but nothing seems to change on the pc! goes to the login screen, once you log in and run a GP result it shows that it's picking up the correct policy.

Answer (score 0):

Did this but all it does is flash up like it runs but nothing seems to change on the pc! goes to the login screen, once you log in and run a GP result it shows that it's picking up the correct policy.  We use a VBS to call the netdom command at startup.  The netdom box flashes up and then when yo ulog in nothing has changed at all.

Can the NetDom command be run at startup with the system account?